# UITableView setEditing not show delete button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use below code show made table become editable, but seem table view not show delete button on left. Why?

```
    - (void)viewListEditale:(NSNotification *)notification{

    NSString *edited = [notification.object objectForKey:@"edit"];

    if ([edited isEqualToString:@"N"]) {
        [_tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }else{
        [_tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem with you.last time I forgotten to call:

```
[super layoutSubviews]
```

when I call

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
```

In my custom Cell.Please check your code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
```